# How to Copy table from one column from one database to other in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have databases name "timetrack" and "nahar". In  databse "timetrack" I have a table "attendence" ,I want to copy table "attedence" from database "timetrack" to database "nahar".

So,Please provide me a way how to do it in SQL SERVER.

Comment: If both databases are in same instance, use this `USE nahar GO  SELECT * into dbo.attendence FROM timetrack.dbo.attendence`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Syntax

```
select *into destinationdb.schema.table from sourcedb.schema.table
```

Example

```
select *into nahar.dbo.attendence from timetrack.dbo.attendence
```

Answer (score 0):

if you did not create the table "attedence" in nahar use this:

```
 select * into nahar.schema.attedence from timetrack.schema.attedence
```

if the table nahar.attedence is alredy exists, just use:

```
insert into nahar.schema.attedence select * from timetrack.schema.attedence
```

if you just want to insert one column into the other db, name it instead of the *

```
select col1 into nahar.schema.attedence from timetrack.schema.attedence
```

or

```
insert into nahar.schema.attedence (col1) select col1 from timetrack.schema.attedence
```